# How to prevent deadlocks in mysql innodb based php SessionHandler

Tags: php, mysql, session, innodb, deadlock

I implemented my own innodb based PHP SessionHandler by implementing the SessionHandlerInterface. Since many simultaneous requests can occur quite often, i have to prevent racing conditions.
My provider doesn't reliable support mutex locks via `SELECT GET LOCK...`. Also I don't want to use filesystem based locking.
So I decided to work with innodb row-based locks.

I aquire the lock within the implemented `SessionHandlerInterface::read()` method via `SELECT ID FROM session FOR UPDATE` (after starting a new transaction) and I release the lock by a `COMMIT` in the `SessionHandlerInterface::write()` method.

Additionally I do a `DELETE FROM session WHERE ID = ?` in the `SessionHandlerInterface::destroy()` method and a `DELETE FROM session WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, access, NOW()) > ?` in the `SessionHandlerInterface::gc()` method.

The `DELETE` within the `SessionHandlerInterface::gc()` method seems to be the query, that produces deadlocks - at least `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` output (example 1).

Summarized (`[...]` = some other code):

```
[...]

protected static function lock($ID)
{
        $e = null;
        $i = 0;
        while($i < 10)
        {
            $e = null;

            try
            {
                DB::startTransaction("START TRANSACTION");
                DB::select("SELECT `ID` FROM `session` FOR UPDATE");
                break;
            }
            catch(MySQLi_SQL_Exception $e)
            {
                if(in_array($e->getCode(), [DB::ER_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT, DB::ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK], true))
                {
                    usleep(10);
                    $i++;
                }
                else
                    throw $e;
            }
        }

        if($e) throw $e;
}

protected static function unlock($ID)
{
    DB::commit("COMMIT");
}

public function read($ID)
{
    self::lock($ID);
    $data = DB::select("SELECT `data` FROM `session` WHERE `ID` = ?", $ID, 'single', '');
    [...]
}

public function write($ID, $data)
{
    [...]
    $insert = (bool) DB::insert("INSERT INTO `session` (`ID`, `data`, `creation`, `access`, `access_micros`, `userAgent`, `IP`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `data` = ?, `access` = ?, `access_micros` = ?", $vals);

    self::unlock($ID);
    [...]
}

public function destroy($ID)
{ 
    return (bool) DB::delete("DELETE FROM `session` WHERE `ID` = ?", [$ID]);
}

public function gc($maxlifetime)
{
    DB::delete("DELETE FROM `session` WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `access`, NOW()) > ?", $maxlifetime);
    return true;
}
```

Since I have not much experience with transactions / deadlocks, I need advice, how I could fix this problem. I am also not sure, if the read and write methods are the right places to start and close the locking transaction.

`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` output (example 1):

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2016-03-08 23:47:51 20a4
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2564667, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 1284, OS thread handle 0x7e8, query id 1028285 localhost 127.0.0.1 U2251792 statistics
SELECT `ID` FROM `session` WHERE `ID` = '76157b19ce3c89f0985b585d8019a5ab0fa6444c6e516a844bd8cea6f6eba357' FOR UPDATE
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 2533 page no 3 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `db2251792`.`session` trx id 2564667 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 9; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 30; hex 373631353762313963653363383966303938356235383564383031396135; asc 76157b19ce3c89f0985b585d8019a5; (total 64 bytes);
1: len 6; hex 000000272233; asc    '"3;;
2: len 7; hex 3b00000152219e; asc ;   R! ;;
3: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
4: len 5; hex 9998d17b78; asc    {x;;
5: len 5; hex 9998d17bf3; asc    { ;;
6: len 3; hex 0e6a93; asc  j ;;
7: len 30; hex 4d6f7a696c6c612f352e30202857696e646f7773204e542031302e303b20; asc Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; ; (total 110 bytes);
8: len 4; hex 7f000001; asc     ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2564660, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read, thread declared inside InnoDB 5000
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
3 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 1281, OS thread handle 0x20a4, query id 1028318 localhost 127.0.0.1 U2251792 updating
DELETE FROM `session` WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `access`, NOW()) > 3600
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 2533 page no 3 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `db2251792`.`session` trx id 2564660 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 9; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 30; hex 373631353762313963653363383966303938356235383564383031396135; asc 76157b19ce3c89f0985b585d8019a5; (total 64 bytes);
1: len 6; hex 000000272233; asc    '"3;;
2: len 7; hex 3b00000152219e; asc ;   R! ;;
3: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
4: len 5; hex 9998d17b78; asc    {x;;
5: len 5; hex 9998d17bf3; asc    { ;;
6: len 3; hex 0e6a93; asc  j ;;
7: len 30; hex 4d6f7a696c6c612f352e30202857696e646f7773204e542031302e303b20; asc Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; ; (total 110 bytes);
8: len 4; hex 7f000001; asc     ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 2533 page no 3 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `db2251792`.`session` trx id 2564660 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 9; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 30; hex 373631353762313963653363383966303938356235383564383031396135; asc 76157b19ce3c89f0985b585d8019a5; (total 64 bytes);
1: len 6; hex 000000272233; asc    '"3;;
2: len 7; hex 3b00000152219e; asc ;   R! ;;
3: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
4: len 5; hex 9998d17b78; asc    {x;;
5: len 5; hex 9998d17bf3; asc    { ;;
6: len 3; hex 0e6a93; asc  j ;;
7: len 30; hex 4d6f7a696c6c612f352e30202857696e646f7773204e542031302e303b20; asc Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; ; (total 110 bytes);
8: len 4; hex 7f000001; asc     ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS output (example 2, different PC):

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2016-03-07 17:47:37 1894
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3925672, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 312, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 25345, OS thread handle 0x3a40, query id 5247758 localhost 127.0.0.1 U2251792 Sending data
SELECT `ID` FROM `session` FOR UPDATE
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 3918 page no 3 n bits 104 index `PRIMARY` of table `db2251792`.`session` trx id 3925672 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 33 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 9; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 30; hex 363039303961363661393234616563366263666232636562346562343162; asc 60909a66a924aec6bcfb2ceb4eb41b; (total 64 bytes);
1: len 6; hex 0000003be6a0; asc    ;  ;;
2: len 7; hex 1d000001ab02e9; asc        ;;
3: len 30; hex 61596d5a57532b752f336945486a645a586a4f45745539387170517a546d; asc aYmZWS+u/3iEHjdZXjOEtU98qpQzTm; (total 192 bytes);
4: len 5; hex 9998cf1bdf; asc      ;;
5: len 5; hex 9998cf1be4; asc      ;;
6: len 3; hex 00023e; asc   >;;
7: len 30; hex 4d6f7a696c6c612f352e30202857696e646f7773204e542031302e303b20; asc Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; ; (total 109 bytes);
8: len 4; hex 7f000001; asc     ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3925665, ACTIVE 1 sec inserting, thread declared inside InnoDB 5000
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
3 lock struct(s), heap size 312, 3 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 25341, OS thread handle 0x1894, query id 5247805 localhost 127.0.0.1 U2251792 update
INSERT INTO `session` (`ID`, `data`, `creation`, `access`, `access_micros`, `userAgent`, `IP`) VALUES ('41e4530eb45871ee64277560290062949b18e6fdb6f8e9cddb097ecd3ccb7c12', '+w1R6dDO2Xx1bzYV4IVt4JV/LFTwb+HtrGvQNK+JgzBs4DQfrjlmUiPX46VjAG0ONjiIHBPiGUAbZXd3Nvy25Lm3pVInq0qkGRDj6GaLVgQ2MSQkjk2YGfY3VMOYRM/23YD6XvPr6DdUIz7120skEBX2SrFUuRX7lBzUZROBJxUVXQ+/mal+paHacMoYJfjF', '2016-03-07 17:47:37', '2016-03-07 17:47:37', 40240, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.75 Safari/537.36', '\0\0') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `data` = '+w1R6dDO2Xx1bzYV4IVt4JV/LFTwb+HtrGvQNK+JgzBs4DQfrjlmUiPX46VjAG0ONjiIHBPiGUAbZXd3Nvy25Lm3pVInq0qkGRDj6GaLVgQ2MSQkjk2YGfY3VMOYRM/23YD6XvPr6DdUIz7120skEBX2SrFUuRX7lBzUZROBJxUVXQ+/mal+paHacMoYJfjF', `access` = '2016-03-07 17:47:37', `access_micros` = 40240
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 3918 page no 3 n bits 104 index `PRIMARY` of table `db2251792`.`session` trx id 3925665 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

Record lock, heap no 33 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 9; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 30; hex 363039303961363661393234616563366263666232636562346562343162; asc 60909a66a924aec6bcfb2ceb4eb41b; (total 64 bytes);
1: len 6; hex 0000003be6a0; asc    ;  ;;
2: len 7; hex 1d000001ab02e9; asc        ;;
3: len 30; hex 61596d5a57532b752f336945486a645a586a4f45745539387170517a546d; asc aYmZWS+u/3iEHjdZXjOEtU98qpQzTm; (total 192 bytes);
4: len 5; hex 9998cf1bdf; asc      ;;
5: len 5; hex 9998cf1be4; asc      ;;
6: len 3; hex 00023e; asc   >;;
7: len 30; hex 4d6f7a696c6c612f352e30202857696e646f7773204e542031302e303b20; asc Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; ; (total 109 bytes);
8: len 4; hex 7f000001; asc     ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 3918 page no 3 n bits 104 index `PRIMARY` of table `db2251792`.`session` trx id 3925665 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 33 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 9; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 30; hex 363039303961363661393234616563366263666232636562346562343162; asc 60909a66a924aec6bcfb2ceb4eb41b; (total 64 bytes);
1: len 6; hex 0000003be6a0; asc    ;  ;;
2: len 7; hex 1d000001ab02e9; asc        ;;
3: len 30; hex 61596d5a57532b752f336945486a645a586a4f45745539387170517a546d; asc aYmZWS+u/3iEHjdZXjOEtU98qpQzTm; (total 192 bytes);
4: len 5; hex 9998cf1bdf; asc      ;;
5: len 5; hex 9998cf1be4; asc      ;;
6: len 3; hex 00023e; asc   >;;
7: len 30; hex 4d6f7a696c6c612f352e30202857696e646f7773204e542031302e303b20; asc Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; ; (total 109 bytes);
8: len 4; hex 7f000001; asc     ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Comment: Why downvote? Without comment? C'mon... Good question. I'd go with memcache session handler and not worry about DB. Do you have apache or a better webserver? Does PHP get loaded on every request or only on .php files?

Comment: Apache 2.4, Don't no (yet), if memcache would be available - did not know about a special handler. PHP gets loaded on nearly every request, because also other resources like js, css or even some images are loaded from the db, at least via php. did not yet optimize http headers - but locks should work properly anyway.

Comment: I have no problems when I use `SELECT GET LOCK`, but my providers environment does not cope with that method (system errors).

Comment: Like @DanFromGermany mentioned, there are better solutions than database based sessions. You can use cookie based sessions where session info gets serialized into text, encrypted, compressed and encoded - which fits into a cookie usually (or you can spread the info across 80 cookies, each able to hold 4kb of data). That way you shift session storage to the client. As for deadlocks - you shouldn't lock the row, you're already in a transaction. If transaction fails, you have to re-try it a few times before giving up. You can't prevent a deadlock, but you can recover from it (by retrying).

Comment: Keep in mind that most locking mechanisms release the lock if there is a network glitch, disconnect, etc.  If you don't watch for that, you could have some "mysterious" bugs in your code.

Comment: @Mjh: The cookie based session solution sounds interesting. I think, I need the locks, since I have concurrent requests / mysql connections. Thanks. Rick Rames: Thanks for the tip/warning.

Comment: MySQL handles concurrency, and transactions isolate the environment. Basically, locks happen internally and MySQL lets you not worry about concurrency.